# Redim Arreglo VBA

Tags: vb.net, vba, vb

tengo un pequeño problema que espero me puedan orientar, resulta que tengo que almacenar un arreglo y por cada dato que voy almacenando verificar si este no ha sido ingresado anteriormente, la dificultad que tengo es que de principio defino un array de 10 elementos, pero puede que el usuario necesite ingresar 15, 20, 30 o n elementos. He intentado usar la instrucción ReDim pero no he logrado hacerlo ya que me sale el error de **La matriz ya tiene dimensiones**

Anexo código si me pueden orientar.

```
 Sub buscarClaves()   
    Dim AClaves(10) As String
    Dim cont As Integer
    cont = 0

 ReDim Preserve AClaves(cont)
    Dim nClave As String

    Do While nClave <> "n"
        nClave = InputBox("Ingrese Clave")
        If bClaves(nClave, AClaves()) Then
            MsgBox ("Clave duplicado")
             Else
                AClaves(cont) = nClave
                cont = cont + 1
           End If
    Loop


    End Sub
```

Funcion para buscar datos repetidos dentro del arreglo.

```
    Function bClaves(ByVal clve As String, ByRef Datos() As String) As Boolean
        bClaves = False
        Dim clave As Variant 

        For Each clave In Datos
            If clave <> "" Then
                If clave = clve Then
                    bClaves = True
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He econtrado la solución a mi problema, anexo código por si a alguien le sirve.

```
Option Explicit
Dim AClaves() As String
Dim impr As String

Sub buscarClaves()
    impr = ""
    Erase AClaves()
    ReDim AClaves(10)

    Dim cont As Integer
    cont = 0
    Dim nClave As String
    Dim iRet As Integer

    Do While nClave <> "n" ' Presionar n para terminar de capturar
        nClave = InputBox("Ingrese Clave")
        If bClaves(nClave, AClaves()) Then
            ' Aca ira la condicion para registrar duplicado o no.
                 iRet = MsgBox("Clave duplicado - ?Desea registrarlo?", vbYesNo, "Registrar claves.")
                 If iRet = vbYes Then
                    If cont > 10 Then
                        ' Si rebasa el indice inicial(en este caso 10 elementos) redimensionar arreglo de 1 en 1
                            ReDim Preserve AClaves(cont)
                    End If
                    AClaves(cont) = nClave
                    cont = cont + 1
                 End If
            Else
                If cont > 10 Then
                MsgBox ("ReDim")
                    ReDim Preserve AClaves(cont)
                End If
                AClaves(cont) = nClave
                cont = cont + 1
              End If
        Loop

    ' Imprimir datos ingresados... Opcional
    Dim nnclave As Variant
    Dim n As Integer
    For n = 0 To UBound(AClaves)
        If AClaves(n) <> "" Then
            impr = impr & " " & AClaves(n)
        End If
    Next n

    MsgBox (impr)

    End Sub

    Function bClaves(ByVal clve As String, ByRef Datos() As String) As Boolean
        bClaves = False
        Dim clave As Variant ' Peticion del VBA
        For Each clave In Datos
            If clave <> "" Then
                If clave = clve Then
                    bClaves = True
                    Exit Function
                End If
            Else
                bClaves = False
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End Function
```